# Can I project 2nd camera view onto a plane?

Tags: camera, eevee-render-engine

I’ve created a cellphone, with hands holding it… Then I created a scene, sort of like a small video game world. So picture this all in 1st person view.

What I’d like to do is have the cellphone screen show what my second camera (which is located on the back of the camera) is looking at. As though I’m using the cellphone to take video of the scene in front of it.

Comment: you could make a first render (cellphone filming) then import the movie and use it as Image Texture on the screen?

Comment: I’m going for a real-time type of thing. That is a good answer though. But not quite what I’m looking for.

Comment: I think it’s quite similar to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/115868/29586 but it would be complicated by the change in size of the screen compared to the “camera” (which would be a surface rather tan a real camera. That might get you some way towards a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I’ll check that out and get back to this post.

Comment: @RichSedman it only works in cycles. That’s exactly what I’m looking for but I need a solution for eevee rather than cycles.

Comment: You’re right - cycles only. I’ve edited the question to include an Eevee tag. Possibly you could setup a multicamera scene and use an ImageTexture as an image sequence picking up the previous frame’s output. It would be one frame behind but could work. Similar to this technique - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/213312/29586

Comment: I’m not sure of how to apply this… I guess I’d need a “for dummies” explanation. But I think I follow what’s being achieved here. What has definitely escaped my understanding is… whether or not this produces a real-time projection in eevee, or is this achieved by rendering to get the result?

Comment: Btw, thank you for you help thus far.

Comment: Yes - it is a quite complicated setup and happy to try and explain it further if it’s a suitable solution. However, it wouldn’t be ‘realtime’ as in instantly viewable in the viewport as the cycles solution would (with Eevee not being raster rather than a pathtracer renderer) - but also wouldn’t need a separate render pass or additional compositor steps. It all depends on your requirement and definition of ‘realtime’ I guess.